# Inserting integer data that has commas

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, scrapy

I am attempting to insert a large set (430 entries) of dictionary entries where one key value pair has a salary associated with it, in the form $xx,xxx,xxx . How do I resolve this, as right now it'll take that one value and split it up into 3 columns.

Edit:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if isinstance(item, TeamStats):
        for key, value in item.iteritems():
            if key == "division":
                print(item.get('division', ""))
                self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO Divs( division ) VALUES(?)", (item.get('division', ""),))
                self.con.commit() 

    if isinstance(item, Player):
        self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO Players(\
            player_name, \
            salary, \
            weight, \
            age, \
            height, \
            position, \
            college \
            ) \
            VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", \
            ( \
            item.get('name', ''),
            item.get('salary', 0),
            item.get('weight', 0),
            item.get('age', 0),
            item.get('height', ''),
            item.get('position', ''),
            item.get('college', '')
            ))

        self.con.commit() 
    return item
```

My object that I am inserting into the pipeline looks like this:

$600,000
2015-01-08 14:17:59-0500 [nbaStats] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 [http://espn.go.com/nba/team/roster/*/name/mil/milwaukee-bucks*](http://espn.go.com/nba/team/roster/_/name/mil/milwaukee-bucks)>
    {'age': u'21',
     'college': u'LSU',
     'height': u'6-9',
     'name': u"Johnny O'Bryant III",
     'position': u'PF',
     'salary': u'$600,000',
     'weight': u'265'}
$5,200,000
2015-01-08 14:17:59-0500 [nbaStats] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 [http://espn.go.com/nba/team/roster//name/mil/milwaukee-bucks](http://espn.go.com/nba/team/roster/_/name/mil/milwaukee-bucks)>
    {'age': u'30',
     'college': u'\xa0',
     'height': u'6-11',
     'name': u'Zaza Pachulia',
     'position': u'C',
     'salary': u'$5,200,000',
     'weight': u'270'}

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could alter your SQL query to remove the commas and dollar signs from the salaries as you insert them. You could do that by changing

```
VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", \
```

to

```
VALUES( ?,    REPLACE(REPLACE(?,',',''),'$',''),   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", \
```

These two nested `REPLACE` operations remove the `,` and `$` characters.

Or you could change your python code to do the removing of the extra characters:

```
        item.get('name', ''),
        re.sub(r'[,$]', "", item.get('salary', 0)),
        item.get('weight', 0),
```

Either way it's simple string processing to clean up the annotated data. Both these methods remove all the dollar signs and commas from the number strings.

Comment: If there are two different salaries, one with the form $xxx,xxx and the other with $xx,xxx,xxx then would i need to alter that with an if statement to check if the salary is either in the first or second?

Comment: Hey Ollie, an additional question, my heights are showing up in a weird format, how should i format them to insert as the string is? 40 of the 437 entries were inputted correctly but the others were not.

Comment: Oh I just realized all the entries that were either 6-0 or 7-0 were inputted correctly, as string, but the other entries (basically all other heights) showed up as a 5 digit number starting with 40xxx